# How do I load an audio source from memory?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I currently have some logic that sends some text to the backend and I get back an audio file representing the speech for that text. The URL is set as the 'src' attribute of the 'audio' element.

The specified endpoint is slow (~3s), so I want to make an HTTP call that fetches the audio data and keep it in memory for a few seconds so that I can use it as the source of the audio element. The audio files can have a size between 300KB and 5MB.

What APIs can I use to store the audio data and how can I then provide that data to the audio element?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you could probably just use the URL as the `src` as you do now, but simply wait to play it until the audio is finished loading. However, some environments will not load `<audio>` sources until the user initiates playing of the audio, so this won't work universally.

Your proposed idea is a good approach. Specifically, you'll want to:

1. Use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch the audio data
2. After the load is compelte, place the data in a `Blob` object
3. use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL from the `Blob`
4. use that URL as the `src` attribute on your `<audio>`

One implementation this would look like

```
fetch("someaudio.ogg")
  .then(response=>response.blob())
  .then(blob=>myAudioElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob))
```

Or with XHR:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.open("GET", "someaudio.ogg");
xhr.send();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    myAudioElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
});
```

Once the fetch completes, `myAudioElem` will be ready with a fully-loaded blob-URL as its `src` attribute. Play should happen immediately, since the network fetch has already been done and the blob URL references locally-cached data.

Comment: Optionally, you can have some CSS that disables the audio controls until the audio has loaded, using an attribute selector like `audio:not([src]) { cursor: wait; pointer-events: none; }` for example.